# How to write adb commands inside a Android application?

Tags: performance, android-activity, adb, android

I want to know how to execute adb commands from within my code. For e.g I want to push a file inside the adb shell and I write this:

```
package org.example.adbshell;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Process process;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb push C:/Users/Savio/Desktop/savio.xml /storage/sdcard0/");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

I should be able to see the savio.xml inside the /storage/sdcard0 folder. But for some reason I am unable to see the file. I am guessing that the command is not getting executed. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There are three type of command

1. System command  // In this case below code is working. like `mv/edit/cp/cd` etc
2. Non routed command
3. Rooted command  // You need to routed device.

Try this

```
Process process Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");

//or

Process process Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/your_command");
```

Its work for me of copying file :

```
Process process Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/mv my_file_path");
```

You can read *output data* with the help of `process` object

```
// Use buffer reader for the same.
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: It's not going to work. ADB is not a valid command on Android.

Comment: @Václav Hodek Yes you are correct but they are still execute some command with some special privilege in phone, like having root permission.

Comment: I just only pointed out that it's not correct solution for given question as the author is asking for ADB specifically and he wants to copy file using it. So running commands on Android is not a solution at all.

Comment: Your code still don't copy files from an attached computer. ADB is not about local operations but about communication between Android and PC. That's unsolvable task with system commands.

Comment: I am sure it will copy the file, I Have tested it. and i have copying my application logs file through this code.

Comment: 1) The mv command don't copy the file but move/rename it instead. 2) It doesn't work for copying files from PC connected via USB to mobile device. 3) The author wants to run ADB specifically and it cannot be replaced by mv or any other command available in Android. 4) Your code can run commands on Android but it is not suitable for solving the original problem in any way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ADB command on Android's side. ADB is a part of Android SDK only and is always run on computer not on Android.

Also, Android knows nothing about C:/Users/Savio/Desktop/savio.xml as it is not a file in its filesystem.

You should rather implement desktop application with HTTP (or similar) server and use it to download and upload files from Android to PC. You can start with NanoHTTP, a lightweight HTTP implementation.

Or you can use server for communication between Android and computer and run ADB command on that computer based upon request from Android.

Comment: yes you can run adb command from a device onto another. i seem it done before, But I dont know how they do it. I think they managed to install adb shell onto the rooted device

Comment: It may be possible to run adb command on rooted device but it still does not solve the problem and it's not helpful to topic author since in no way it can be used to transfer files from computer.